# Flash firmware on a Micron OEM SSD (P400m)

Tags: ssd, firmware

I have a 100 GB Micron P400m SSD from an EMC VMAX array. The sector size is 520 or 528 bits. I can identify the drive with everything via the tools from Micron, but it refuses to download the firmware or even upload.

Is there a way to re-flash it with **different** *firmware*? I know [Crucial](https://store.cmsdistribution.com/ssd-enterprise/crucial-micron-p400m-200gb-sata-2.5-ssd/) or Cisco products of containing the same SSD drive allow such firmware updates.

Comment: Not sure if it is off-topic. I use enterprise hardware at home in very unprofessional ways (e.g. RAID 5 on huge SATA disks, old 4GB (Yes GB, not TB) SCSI drives which I low leveled from 528 to 512 byte sectors, ...)  Both off topic on SF. Having said that I **do** agree that it very likely is a better fit.

Comment: It looks like I might have misread the question - retracted the vote and edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for the edit but it is not correct one.  Since it is OEM from Micron the Crucial and Cisco are using the same drive p400m (only under different name).  I was not sure if to write it to SU or SF (on borderline).

Comment: @Hannes yes, it is enterprise HW which will have home use.  I don't like to thow away fully functional HW when it is at about 10% of its lifetime expectancy.

Comment: @bwDraco thank you, I have reedited it with a link and hopefully better meaning.